# Unique values within folder

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am stumped on how to implement this.

How can I keep a set of unique values (on a custom column) on each set of folders.

Say the custom column is called 'Country' and it can contain

- USA
- Canada
- Mexico

There is 3 folders under a document library. Each folder should be able to have 1 set of above countries only. If I check on the 'enforce unique values' option, it applies it to all of the library hence allowing only one country for the entire library. I want one country per folder as unique. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this with OOB.

1. Create a new column having folder name (you can use drop down or Radio button).
2. Choose the folder name of each single record of the country name.
3. Then group the data on the basis of this column (folder name)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick solution. I am stuck on #3. How do you 'group the data' using this column?

Comment: from the view settings..

Comment: Hi @cjs, unfortunately this does not solve the issue as when I upload a file in to adjacent folder with same country, it says duplicate exists ( and would not let me upload)

Comment: hi @Dingo ,  if I got you requirement correct than,  you need some folder/group with unique metadata column value.   For which I suggest to create new column with folder name and tag each entry with this column.   Now I am wondering where this Folder come from ! ;)

Comment: Ow there is 3 folders under library. I want it so that each folder can have USA, Canada & Mexico as items (only once) If I enforce uniqueness on these countries column, then it applies to entire library which means I can only have 1 folder with these 3 counties. Other folders I am unable to select them. That is the issue. Sorry if I mistyped it.

Comment: the solution I suggested doesn't include folder creation, instead of folder you can group the entries  by the custom column.   If you need to create folder, than I guess we need to find some other solution.   :)